# Windows 10 SSD drive

Tags: windows-10, ssd

I installed a 120GB SSD as a C drive and took out the old 500 GB hard drive in the C drive and put it into SATA CD drive (caddy) connection as D drive to store files. I tried to install Windows 10 which was a successful installation, but it doesn't see the D drive. I can see it in the BIOS, but not in Windows. I tried to delete MBR and recreate it during install. I also tried a couple of programs to check the drive, but none of them worked. What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you detect the drive in disk management?

Comment: It does see it but all grayed out. Nothing can be done in disk management

Comment: That might mean you have to bring the disk online. Have you tried right-clicking the left side of the bar and seeing what options you get there. You might have to bring the disk online.

Comment: I don't get too many options except properties which doesn't give a lot.

Comment: How exactly did you "delete MBR and recreate during install"? Have you try "clean" of "diskpart" and then see if you can re-initialize the drive (with mbr or gpt) in "disk management"? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: During windows 10 installation, you are asked where you want to install the OS, and there is an option to delete and recreate MBR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GParted](http://gparted.org/download.php) from live disc to verify the filesystem on that disk and format/repartition it to suit your needs.